Kalman filter implementation
I’m implementing an extended kalman filter in melodic ros using odometry to estimate and a gps to correct. I noticed that the robot in question already provides the estimation of its linear and angular position (probably integrating through another filter the data of its encoders and imu) via the topic /odom. My question is whether I can directly use this estimate for the prediction phase without implementing a state transition model and set the state transition matrix as a simple identity matrix by directly transforming the extended filter into a state transition Linear kalman. Thank you for your attention.

I don't know if my answer can be helpful, but there is a ROS package for the EKF at this link

Thanks for answering but the idea would be to implement it and use the positions given by topic /odom because, being the quadrupedal robot, I would avoid the complicated part of the prediction since it is already provided through the topic /odom

you may be interested in using the robot_localization package.
It seems suited for your case as it takes in input (among the others) odometry message and gps messages and utilize an EKF to compute a filtered pose.
So it seems that you could use it in your case with a simple configuration of the package without implementing the algorithm yourself.
Be aware that the package has some limitations, from the original paper it can be seen how the state transition function can't be defined and it follows a simple 3D kinematic model. Moreover the observation Matrix instead of being the jacobian of the measurement function is simply the identity matrix.
References:
Moore, T., & Stouch, D. (2015). A Generalized Extended Kalman Filter Implementation for the Robot Operating System. Advances in Intelligent Systems and Computing, 335–348.

Thank you as well for answering but the idea would be to implement it and use the positions given by topic /odom because, being the quadrupedal robot, I would avoid the complicated part of the prediction since it is already provided through the topic /odom

You could then use a similar approach to robot_localization where the state transition function is approximated to a standard model so that you don't need to write the prediction function.

I explain better, the topic /odom already provides a position (frame body compared to frame odom) that I would use as an estimate without creating a model and then correct these estimates with a gps. Is it an approach that can work?  And then, creating a global frame called map, how can I update the transform between map and odom, so that it has the correct position with respect to map?
Sorry for the questions but I’m really desperate and I don’t know who to ask.
